# App falling down when Internet restored, RxJava & Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to get data from Api for each list element also I need to implement Internet connection checker.

1. Then program starts everything works great.
2. I disable Internet on live, and run method again (using swipeRefreshLayout), I receive InternetErrorToast, great!
3. I restored Internet on live, and run method again (using swipeRefreshLayout), app crashed with error.

Now I have following method.
Note! dataManager.getCityConditionsResponse() return Single

```
@Override
public void updateCitiesList() {
    List<City> citiesList = dataManager.getCitiesFromDb();
    if (!dataManager.isInternetConnected()) {
        view.showCitiesList(citiesList);
        view.showInternetErrorToast();
    } else {
        compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromIterable(citiesList)
                .doOnNext(city -> dataManager.getCityConditionsResponse(city.getQuery())
                        .subscribe(
                                response -> {
                                    city.setTemp(response.getTemp());
                                    city.setIcon(response.getIcon());
                                },
                                error -> view.showServerErrorToast()))
                .toList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        list -> view.showCitiesList(list),
                        error -> view.showServerErrorToast()
                ));
    }
    view.hideRefreshingStatus();
}
```

On step 3 I have this error

```
018-10-12 16:34:54.033 19013-19046/mike.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: mike.weather, PID: 19013
io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onError(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onError(ObservableSingleSingle.java:93)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onError(BodyObservable.java:72)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:56)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12090)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12090)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3438)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3424)
    at mike.weather.ui.main.MainActivityPresenter.lambda$updateCitiesList$3(MainActivityPresenter.java:49)
    at mike.weather.ui.main.-$$Lambda$MainActivityPresenter$UqLPaAef0SB9PT-Rz654tgX3dnA.accept(Unknown Source:4)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:93)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:101)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable$FromIterableDisposable.run(ObservableFromIterable.java:98)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromIterable.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12090)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12090)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12090)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableToListSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableToListSingle.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3438)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3438)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  ........................
```

Comment: Hi, can you remove the inner subscribe() method and replace with map(). You can subscribe to a stream only once. In your case you have subscribed twice.

Comment: Hi, I just replaced subscribe(), but how can I call two setters (Temp and Icon). Now Android studio says that I have error. It says missing return statement. Sorry I am newer with RxJava.

**.map(response -> {
                                city.setTemp(response.getTemp());
                                city.setIcon(response.getIcon());
                            })**

Comment: Info updated! dataManager.getCityConditionsResponse() return Single<ConditionsResponse>

Comment: You can do something like this:
*.map(response -> city.setTemp(response.getTemp())).map(response ->city.setIcon(response.getIcon()))* assuming that setTemp() and setIcon() return same *response*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more Rx idiomatic if you rewrite your observable like that

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromArray(citiesList)
            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
            .flatMapSingle(city -> 
                dataManager.getCityConditionsResponse(city.getQuery())
                    .map(response -> { 
                        city.setTemp(response.getTemp());
                        city.setIcon(response.getIcon()); 
                        return city;
                    })
            )
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    list -> view.showCitiesList(list),
                    error -> view.showServerErrorToast()
            ));
```

After that I think you problem will disappear.

Comment: Hi! I receive error from Android Stuido(No instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Single<T> conforms to Iterable<? extends U>). Note that dataManager.getCityConditionsResponse() return Singe<ConditionsRepsonse>

Comment: Yep! But I have list, so I think in first line we need to replace fromArray() to fromIterable(), and second line must be deleted. I applied this, and everything compiles. But on Step 3 running method showServerErrorToast instead of showCitiesList

Comment: Well! Everything works ok, but if in emulator I turn off wi-fi and enabled only cellular data in poor / moderate mode, happening execution onError method, but if Internet connection good, everything works fine. Probably, I need to make additional handling for bad Internet connection

Comment: @Mike, if you have network error and want always display cities stored in DB you can use one of operators to handle error described here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators